# how to use user id stored in session with ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, session

When the user login I am storing the userid into session and then I want to pass that user id to the ajax to retriever other information form the data base.
userid stored in session is not being passed to allResult.php
My login page code snippet where i make the session:

```
  $msg = '';

  if (isset($_POST['login']) && !empty($_POST['username']) 
   && !empty($_POST['password']))
  {
   $username1 = $_POST['username'];
   $password1 = $_POST['password'];
   $password2 = md5($password1);
   $sql= "SELECT * FROM users WHERE userName='$username1' AND password='$password2'";
   if($query_run = mysqli_query($conn, $sql))
   {
    $query_num_rows = mysqli_num_rows($query_run);
    $stmt =mysqli_prepare($conn, $sql);
    mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
    mysqli_stmt_store_result($stmt);
    if($query_num_rows==1)
    {
     $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query_run);
     $user_id =  $row['id'];
     $name=$row['Name'];
      //creating session

     $_SESSION['loggedin_time'] = time();
     $_SESSION['userid'] = $user_id;
     $_SESSION['name'] = $name;

   }
 }
  else {
       $msg = '*Wrong username or password';
     }
}
```

Now after login the user will be taken to dashboard:

```
<?php 
  session_start();
  include("functions.php");
  if(isset($_SESSION["userid"])) {
    if(isLoginSessionExpired()) {
      header("Location:loginPage.php");
    }
  }
  if($_SESSION['userid']=="" && $_SESSION['name']==""){
    header("location: loginPage.php");
  }
  require 'dbconnect.php'; 
  $userId = $_SESSION['userid'];   
  echo "$userId"; 
  ?>
```

in the dashboard i am trying to access the other data of the user with ajax

```
      <script id="source" language="javascript" type="text/javascript">


          $(function() {
            $( "#tabs" ).tabs({active:0});
            $.ajax({                                      
              url: 'allResult.php',
              method:"POST",
              data: ({uid:'$userId'}),                                                      
              dataType: 'json',                     
              success: function(data)         
              {

                var date=  data[0]['date'];
                   var time=  data[0]['time']; 
                   var ip=  data[0]['ip'];
                   var lux=  data[0]['lux'];
                   var press=  data[0]['press'];
                   var acc_x=  data[0]['acc_x'];
                   var acc_y=  data[0]['acc_y'];
                   var acc_z=  data[0]['acc_z'];



                   $("#tabs-1").html("<b>date: </b>"+date+"<b> time: </b>"+time+"<b> ip: </b>"+ip+"<b> lux: </b>"+lux+"<b> press: </b>"+press+"<b> acc_x: </b>"+acc_x+"<b> acc_y: </b>"+acc_y+"<b> acc_z: </b>"+acc_z);

             } ,
             error : function(request,error) 

             { 
              alert (error);
              alert("Request: "+JSON.stringify(request)); 
            } 

          });
});
```

I need to get the user id in order to run allResult.php 
allResult.php

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
    ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
    error_reporting(E_ALL);
    require 'dbconnect.php';
    $user_id =  $_POST["uid"]
    $sql_query = "SELECT * FROM data where id like '$user_id';";          
    $result = mysqli_query($conn,$sql_query);  
     if(mysqli_num_rows($result) >0 )  
     {  
     $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);  

     $output [] = $row ;

     echo json_encode($output);
     }  
     else  
     {   
     echo "Error finding data..";  
     }  

    ?>
```

Comment: so whats the problem?

Comment: Don't want to read all the code but I think this might help `<?php echo session_id();?>`

Comment: user id is not being passed to allResult.php

Answer (score 0):

Make all your user logged in data to be called into a json format.

Assuming you have all data under

> somedomain.com/userData.php

```
<?php
#userData.php

if ($user == "loggedin") {
  $data['name'] = $_SESSION[1]; //name
  $data['email'] = $_SESSION[2]; //email
  $data['extra'] = $_SESSION[3]; //etc.
  echo json_encode($data, JSON_PREETY_PRINT);
}
?>
```

Then get data into realtime using jQuery Ajax.

Answer (score -1):

Looks like you're missing session_start()

Comment: Besides being incorrect, this answer doesn't go into much details. If your answer is gonna fit in one line, you should probably not post it.